# Quitar carácter b en array

Tags: python, array

me gustaría almacenar solamente los nombres de archivos y directorios en un array con el comando ls junto awk, pero en el array también se almacena el caracter "b" y eso me genera problemas al extraer valores del array, este es el código:

```
    lista=subprocess.check_output("ls -l / | awk '{print $9}'",shell=True)
    lista2=lista.splitlines()
    print(lista2)
```

Salida del array:

```
[b'', b'bin', b'boot', b'dev', b'etc', b'home', b'initrd.img', b'initrd.img.old', b'lib', b'lib32', b'lib64', b'libx32', b'lost+found', b'media', b'mnt', b'opt', b'proc', b'root', b'run', b'sbin', b'srv', b'sys', b'tmp', b'usr', b'var', b'VBox.log', b'vmlinuz', b'vmlinuz.old']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque cada una de las cadenas del array esta codificada como una cadena de bytes. Si quieres que las cadenas empleen otra codificación debes usar el método [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Si haces

```
> b'¡hola mundo!'.decode()
```

deberías obtener

```
> '¡hola mundo!'
```

Para transformar todas las cadenas de tu array puedes emplear [map()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map)

```
map(lambda x : x.decode(), lista2)
```

Ten en cuenta que esto te devolverá un objeto map como resultado si usas python 3.+. Si quieres una lista deberás hacer un cast empleando list()

```
 list(map(lambda x : x.decode(), lista2))
```

O tambien puedes usar list comprehension

```
lista2 = [x.decode() for x in lista2]
```

Answer (score 0):

La b se refiere a bytes, subprocess parece retornar este tipo para que el usuario puede darle el formato de codificación deseado. Puedes usar lists comprehension para convertir los elementos a utf-8, por ejemplo, de la siguiente manera:

`[x.decode("utf-8") for x in lista2]`

Answer (score 0):

Buscando mas sobre subprocess, encontre que si le agregas `universal_newlines=True` despues de `shell = true` si te muestra como quires

codigo de ejemplo:

```
import subprocess
import sys

lista=subprocess.check_output("ls -l / | awk '{print $9}'",shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
lista2=lista.splitlines()
print(lista2)
```

resultado:

```
['', 'bin', 'boot', 'cdrom', 'dev'....]
```